# Does SVG not work like conventional DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am just starting out with SVGs. I have noticed that even with SVG and exactly the same DOM, the results may look different on the display.

Look at this js fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/ZHukw/). Its a simple rectangle inside SVG canvas.

The rectangle is visible if you copy paste the rectangle node directly into HTML but if you add the rectangle through Jquery, it simply wont show on screen. So the final DOM output is same but display is different.

Am I missing something?

HTML:

```
<svg id='svg'>

</svg>
```

JS:

```
$('#svg').attr('width',1600)
$('#svg').attr('height',1600)

$('#svg').append('<rect width="200" height="200" fill="black"></rect>')
```

Comment: You probably have namespacing issues as SVG resides not in the usual HTML namespace. You might want to check out [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).

Comment: Also consider [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) instead of jQuery for SVG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with adding the `rect` element as text is that it gets interpreted in the wrong namespace (HTML instead of SVG). When you're specifying it statically, the namespace is obvious from the context.

One fix is to explicitly create the node with the correct namespace and append it.

```
var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "rect");
el.setAttribute("width", 200);
el.setAttribute("height", 200);
el.setAttribute("fill", "black");
$('#svg').appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip! This works with .append instead of appendChild